# Importing data from MySQL to MySQL using Apache Sqoop

Tags: java, mysql, sqoop

I want to know if Apache Sqoop gives us the option to import data from MySQL to MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

## Not directly... but yes you can...

Sqoop is for RDBMS to HDFS and HDFS to RDBMS.

But you can achieve your requirement by first import into hdfs from mysql and then you can again export into mysql..

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_introduction